# How to format median and errors differently in corner plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mcmc, emcee

I'm trying to format a corner plot using the `corner` package in Python. As far as I know, there's the command `title_fmt = *arg`, however it gives the same format to both the median and the errors, which is inconvenient for reporting measurement errors. I need the error to be shown with 2 significant figures, and then the median to be rounded at the last sig.fig. of its error. Here's an example of what I can do

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import corner

np.random.seed(539)

#   generate data
data = np.random.randn(5000,3)
data[:,0] = data[:,0]*20 + 150.75
data[:,1] = data[:,1] + 7.52
data[:,2] = data[:,2]*5 + 31.25

#   make plot
labels = ['x','y','f']
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7,7),dpi=100)
fig=corner.corner(
    data, labels=labels, quantiles=(0.16, 0.84),show_titles=True,
    title_fmt='g', use_math_text=True, fig=fig)
fig.show()
```

which gives

[image: results of the latter code]

I could enter a line like `title_fmt = '.2g'` which gives

[image: result formatting as '.2g']

Where as expected shows less sig.fig. for the errors, but then I'm missing sig.fig. in the median and some of the errors don't display the last sig.fig. when it's 0. For my example I'd need to get something like

```
x = 151 +20
        -19
y = 7.5 +1.0
        -1.0
f = 31.3 +5.2
         -5.0
```

I've read the API and it doesn't give any more explanations beyond the `title_fmt` option. If anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`title_fmt = '.2f'` should format numbers with 2 decimal places.
Here you have all possible formatting options:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Your proposal makes all numbers show 2 decimal places, while instead what I need is to show 2 [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) for the errors, and enough significant figures in the median up to the last figure of the error, as shown below the sentence ' For my example I'd need...'

Comment: You can round the errors before formatting them:

significant_digits = 2
rounded_number =  round(number, significant_digits - int(math.floor(math.log10(abs(number)))) - 1)