# How to print significant digits only?

Tags: python, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have not found an answer for this...

Suppose I have the following rational numbers:
0.00000857 and 1.03.

Using %f rounds to 6 digits so 0.00000857 becomes 0.000009. Also 1.03 would be padded to 1.030000. Setting .8f would print 0.00000857 as 0.00000857, but 1.03 would be padded. %g returns exponential notation and I do not want it.

How can I print (stringify) the two numbers as they are, i.e. 0.00000857 and 1.03?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972737/how-to-format-median-and-errors-differently-in-corner-plots/65976170?noredirect=1#comment116654449_65976170

Comment: There's probably a better way, but this works `"{0:.8f}".format(x).rstrip('0')`

Comment: What do you mean by "as they are"? Are you familiar with how computers treat floating-point numbers? If not, please look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just round the float to desired decimal places(6 in your case) and subsequently formate it to such.

```
print('{:.6f}'.format(0.00000857))
```

to remove the undesirable trailing zeros:

```
print('{:.6f}'.format(1.03).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
```

Comment: As I said, this would print 1.030000 instead of 1.03.

Comment: Hope this could achieve your needs        print('{:.6f}'.format(1.03).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

Comment: Please refer to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440786/6521915